# Plank not starting after reinstall

Tags: plank, desktop, startup

I am having some issues with Plank, so I uninstalled it by doing `apt remove --purge plank`. After reinstalling it, I could run the dock by starting it on the command line, but it would not start with the desktop.

I tried putting it on the startup applications on Switchboard, but it would not work anyway. How can I make plank startup automatically again on login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled via a dconf setting in Loki:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere monitored-processes`

It should contain `plank` (the default is `['wingpanel', 'plank']`). If plank is not listed, you can just add it:

`gsettings set org.pantheon.desktop.cerbere monitored-processes "['wingpanel', 'plank']"`

Comment: On ElementaryOS Hera the path is slightly different: `io.elementary.desktop.cerbere monitored-processes`